# Почему кнопка "назад" не работает?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.d-flex');
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.d-flex .item');
var itemsCount = items.length;
var itemWidth = document.querySelector('.d-flex .item').offsetWidth;
var nextLink = document.querySelector('#nextSlide');
var prevLink = document.querySelector('#prevSlide');
var slidesToScroll = 1;
var slidesToShow = 4;
var currentIndex = 0;
var indexDiv = document.querySelector('#index');
var autoSlide = () => setTimeout(nextSlide, 3000);

var nextSlide = function(){

  
  

 // container.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("t.slide"));
 
  var cloned = items[currentIndex];
  
 function  rc(){
   items[currentIndex].remove();
    container.appendChild(cloned);
   currentIndex++;
 }
    function addm(){
      
      items[currentIndex].style.marginLeft = -itemWidth;
      setTimeout(function(){
        rc()
      },300)
  

      
    }
  
    addm()
    

  
    
 if (currentIndex >= itemsCount-1){
     
   currentIndex = 0;
   } 
  indexDiv.innerText = currentIndex;
  
  }

var prevSlide = function(){
  if(currentIndex === 1){
    return;
  }
  currentIndex--;
  var ml = parseInt(items[0].style.marginLeft);
  items[currentIndex-1].style.marginLeft = +ml+itemWidth;
  
}

nextLink.addEventListener("click", nextSlide);
prevLink.addEventListener("click", prevSlide);
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.d-flex{
  display:flex;
  padding:20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  overflow:hidden;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.d-flex .item{
  justify-content:center;
  flex: 1 0 25%;
  padding:10px;
  order:-1;
 transition:margin 0.2s ease-out; 
  box-sizing:border-box;
  
}

.d-flex .item span{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  border:2px solid #999;
  background:#ccc;
  height:100px;
  font-size:60px;
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  font-family:"Open Sans";
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:bold;
  align-items:center;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  justify-content:center;
  border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="index">0</div>
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="item"><div class="name"><a class="deshevo" rel="nofollow" title="Москва Астрахань 2998 руб. " href="flights/?origin_iata=MOW&amp;destination_iata=ASF&amp;depart_date=2021-11-25&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;infants=0&amp;trip_class=0&amp;marker=87111&amp;with_request=true" target="_blank"><div class="col span_1_of_3">
<div class="over"></div>
<div class="ima">
<div style="width: 100%;     line-height: 1; margin-left:5px;position: relative; z-index: 99999; padding: 0px; float: none; display: inline-block;" class="titles"><span class="tow">Москва - <br>Астрахань</span></div> <p><img style="    padding: 2px;background: white; " width="66" height="38" src="/88/48/DP.jpg" class="lazyload air"></p>
<span style="left: 5px;line-height: 1;color:#fce68c!important;font-size: 20px!important;border-radius: 5px;padding-left: 5px;top: 100px;width:160px;text-align: center;" class="titles">Билеты от 2998  р.</span>
</div>
<img width="220" height="220" alt="купить авиабилет Москва Астрахань" src="/static/cities/220x150/ASF.webp" class="lazyload content-image"><p></p>
</div></a></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="name"><a class="deshevo" rel="nofollow" title="Москва Брянск 3141 руб. " href="/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&amp;destination_iata=BZK&amp;depart_date=2021-08-01&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;infants=0&amp;trip_class=0&amp;marker=87111&amp;with_request=true" target="_blank"><div class="col span_1_of_3">
<div class="over"></div>
<div class="ima">
<div style="width: 100%;     line-height: 1; margin-left:5px;position: relative; z-index: 99999; padding: 0px; float: none; display: inline-block;" class="titles"><span class="tow">Москва - <br>Брянск</span></div> <p><img style="    padding: 2px;background: white; " width="66" height="38" src="/88/48/S7.jpg" class="lazyload air"></p>
<span style="left: 5px;line-height: 1;color:#fce68c!important;font-size: 20px!important;border-radius: 5px;padding-left: 5px;top: 100px;width:160px;text-align: center;" class="titles">Билеты от 3141  р.</span>
</div>
<img width="220" height="220" alt="купить авиабилет Москва Брянск" src="/static/cities/220x150/BZK.webp" class="lazyload content-image"><p></p>
</div></a></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="name"><a class="deshevo" rel="nofollow" title="Москва Ярославль 3000 руб. " href="/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&amp;destination_iata=IAR&amp;depart_date=2021-07-19&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;infants=0&amp;trip_class=0&amp;marker=87111&amp;with_request=true" target="_blank"><div class="col span_1_of_3">
<div class="over"></div>
<div class="ima">
<div style="width: 100%;     line-height: 1; margin-left:5px;position: relative; z-index: 99999; padding: 0px; float: none; display: inline-block;" class="titles"><span class="tow">Москва - <br>Ярославль</span></div> <p><img style="    padding: 2px;background: white; " width="66" height="38" src="/88/48/SU.jpg" class="lazyload air"></p>
<span style="left: 5px;line-height: 1;color:#fce68c!important;font-size: 20px!important;border-radius: 5px;padding-left: 5px;top: 100px;width:160px;text-align: center;" class="titles">Билеты от 3000  р.</span>
</div>
<img width="220" height="220" alt="купить авиабилет Москва Ярославль" src="/static/cities/220x150/IAR.webp" class="lazyload content-image"><p></p>
</div></a></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="name"><a class="deshevo" rel="nofollow" title="Москва Ижевск 2998 руб. " href="/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&amp;destination_iata=IJK&amp;depart_date=2021-11-01&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;infants=0&amp;trip_class=0&amp;marker=87111&amp;with_request=true" target="_blank"><div class="col span_1_of_3">
<div class="over"></div>
<div class="ima">
<div style="width: 100%;     line-height: 1; margin-left:5px;position: relative; z-index: 99999; padding: 0px; float: none; display: inline-block;" class="titles"><span class="tow">Москва - <br>Ижевск</span></div> <p><img style="    padding: 2px;background: white; " width="66" height="38" src="/88/48/DP.jpg" class="lazyload air"></p>
<span style="left: 5px;line-height: 1;color:#fce68c!important;font-size: 20px!important;border-radius: 5px;padding-left: 5px;top: 100px;width:160px;text-align: center;" class="titles">Билеты от 2998  р.</span>
</div>
<img width="220" height="220" alt="купить авиабилет Москва Ижевск" src="/static/cities/220x150/IJK.webp" class="lazyload content-image"><p></p>
</div></a></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="name"><a class="deshevo" rel="nofollow" title="Москва Калининград 2920 руб. " href="/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&amp;destination_iata=KGD&amp;depart_date=2021-10-09&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;infants=0&amp;trip_class=0&amp;marker=87111&amp;with_request=true" target="_blank"><div class="col span_1_of_3">
<div class="over"></div>
<div class="ima">
<div style="width: 100%;     line-height: 1; margin-left:5px;position: relative; z-index: 99999; padding: 0px; float: none; display: inline-block;" class="titles"><span class="tow">Москва - <br>Калининград</span></div> <p><img style="    padding: 2px;background: white; " width="66" height="38" src="/88/48/UT.jpg" class="lazyload air"></p>
<span style="left: 5px;line-height: 1;color:#fce68c!important;font-size: 20px!important;border-radius: 5px;padding-left: 5px;top: 100px;width:160px;text-align: center;" class="titles">Билеты от 2920  р.</span>
</div>
<img width="220" height="220" alt="купить авиабилет Москва Калининград" src="/static/cities/220x150/KGD.webp" class="lazyload content-image"><p></p>
</div></a></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="name"><a class="deshevo" rel="nofollow" title="Москва Краснодар 2998 руб. " href="/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&amp;destination_iata=KRR&amp;depart_date=2021-11-15&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;infants=0&amp;trip_class=0&amp;marker=87111&amp;with_request=true" target="_blank"><div class="col span_1_of_3">
<div class="over"></div>
<div class="ima">
<div style="width: 100%;     line-height: 1; margin-left:5px;position: relative; z-index: 99999; padding: 0px; float: none; display: inline-block;" class="titles"><span class="tow">Москва - <br>Краснодар</span></div> <p><img style="    padding: 2px;background: white; " width="66" height="38" src="/88/48/DP.jpg" class="lazyload air"></p>
<span style="left: 5px;line-height: 1;color:#fce68c!important;font-size: 20px!important;border-radius: 5px;padding-left: 5px;top: 100px;width:160px;text-align: center;" class="titles">Билеты от 2998  р.</span>
</div>
<img width="220" height="220" alt="купить авиабилет Москва Краснодар" src="/static/cities/220x150/KRR.webp" class="lazyload content-image"><p></p>
</div></a></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="name"><a class="deshevo" rel="nofollow" title="Москва Санкт-Петербург 2990 руб. " href="/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&amp;destination_iata=LED&amp;depart_date=2021-08-16&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;infants=0&amp;trip_class=0&amp;marker=87111&amp;with_request=true" target="_blank"><div class="col span_1_of_3">
<div class="over"></div>
<div class="ima">
<div style="width: 100%;     line-height: 1; margin-left:5px;position: relative; z-index: 99999; padding: 0px; float: none; display: inline-block;" class="titles"><span class="tow">Москва - <br>Санкт-Петербург</span></div> <p><img style="    padding: 2px;background: white; " width="66" height="38" src="/88/48/UT.jpg" class="lazyload air"></p>
<span style="left: 5px;line-height: 1;color:#fce68c!important;font-size: 20px!important;border-radius: 5px;padding-left: 5px;top: 100px;width:160px;text-align: center;" class="titles">Билеты от 2990  р.</span>
</div>
<img width="220" height="220" alt="купить авиабилет Москва Санкт-Петербург" src="/static/cities/220x150/LED.webp" class="lazyload content-image"><p></p>
</div></a></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="name"><a class="deshevo" rel="nofollow" title="Москва Лондон 2924 руб. " href="/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&amp;destination_iata=LON&amp;depart_date=2021-10-18&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;infants=0&amp;trip_class=0&amp;marker=87111&amp;with_request=true" target="_blank"><div class="col span_1_of_3">
<div class="over"></div>
<div class="ima">
<div style="width: 100%;     line-height: 1; margin-left:5px;position: relative; z-index: 99999; padding: 0px; float: none; display: inline-block;" class="titles"><span class="tow">Москва - <br>Лондон</span></div> <p><img style="    padding: 2px;background: white; " width="66" height="38" src="/88/48/W9.jpg" class="lazyload air"></p>
<span style="left: 5px;line-height: 1;color:#fce68c!important;font-size: 20px!important;border-radius: 5px;padding-left: 5px;top: 100px;width:160px;text-align: center;" class="titles">Билеты от 2924  р.</span>
</div>
<img width="220" height="220" alt="купить авиабилет Москва Лондон" src="/static/cities/220x150/LON.webp" class="lazyload content-image"><p></p>
</div></a></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="name"><a class="deshevo" rel="nofollow" title="Москва Владикавказ 2998 руб. " href="/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&amp;destination_iata=OGZ&amp;depart_date=2021-11-15&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;infants=0&amp;trip_class=0&amp;marker=87111&amp;with_request=true" target="_blank"><div class="col span_1_of_3">
<div class="over"></div>
<div class="ima">
<div style="width: 100%;     line-height: 1; margin-left:5px;position: relative; z-index: 99999; padding: 0px; float: none; display: inline-block;" class="titles"><span class="tow">Москва - <br>Владикавказ</span></div> <p><img style="    padding: 2px;background: white; " width="66" height="38" src="/88/48/DP.jpg" class="lazyload air"></p>
<span style="left: 5px;line-height: 1;color:#fce68c!important;font-size: 20px!important;border-radius: 5px;padding-left: 5px;top: 100px;width:160px;text-align: center;" class="titles">Билеты от 2998  р.</span>
</div>
<img width="220" height="220" alt="купить авиабилет Москва Владикавказ" src="/static/cities/220x150/OGZ.webp" class="lazyload content-image"><p></p>
</div></a></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="name"><a class="deshevo" rel="nofollow" title="Москва Псков 2960 руб. " href="/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&amp;destination_iata=PKV&amp;depart_date=2021-09-06&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;infants=0&amp;trip_class=0&amp;marker=87111&amp;with_request=true" target="_blank"><div class="col span_1_of_3">
<div class="over"></div>
<div class="ima">
<div style="width: 100%;     line-height: 1; margin-left:5px;position: relative; z-index: 99999; padding: 0px; float: none; display: inline-block;" class="titles"><span class="tow">Москва - <br>Псков</span></div> <p><img style="    padding: 2px;background: white; " width="66" height="38" src="/88/48/A4.jpg" class="lazyload air"></p>
<span style="left: 5px;line-height: 1;color:#fce68c!important;font-size: 20px!important;border-radius: 5px;padding-left: 5px;top: 100px;width:160px;text-align: center;" class="titles">Билеты от 2960  р.</span>
</div>
<img width="220" height="220" alt="купить авиабилет Москва Псков" src="/static/cities/220x150/PKV.webp" class="lazyload content-image"><p></p>
</div></a></div></div>
  <div class="item"><div class="name"><a class="deshevo" rel="nofollow" title="Москва Ульяновск 2998 руб. " href="/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&amp;destination_iata=ULY&amp;depart_date=2021-08-31&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;infants=0&amp;trip_class=0&amp;marker=87111&amp;with_request=true" target="_blank"><div class="col span_1_of_3">
<div class="over"></div>
<div class="ima">
<div style="width: 100%;     line-height: 1; margin-left:5px;position: relative; z-index: 99999; padding: 0px; float: none; display: inline-block;" class="titles"><span class="tow">Москва - <br>Ульяновск</span></div> <p><img style="    padding: 2px;background: white; " width="66" height="38" src="/88/48/DP.jpg" class="lazyload air"></p>
<span style="left: 5px;line-height: 1;color:#fce68c!important;font-size: 20px!important;border-radius: 5px;padding-left: 5px;top: 100px;width:160px;text-align: center;" class="titles">Билеты от 2998  р.</span>
</div>
<img width="220" height="220" alt="купить авиабилет Москва Ульяновск" src="/static/cities/220x150/ULY.webp" class="lazyload content-image"><p></p>
</div></a></div></div>
</div>
<button id="prevSlide" style="position: relative; left: 8px;cursor:pointer;padding: 5px; background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 10% 20%, #c2d7ec 0, #ffffff 90%); border: 1px solid #999; border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;margin-left:20px;margin-top: 10px; ">Назад</button>
<button id="nextSlide" style="cursor:pointer;padding: 5px; background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 10% 20%, #ffffff 0, #c2d7ec 90%); border: 1px solid #999; border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px; ">Вперед</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Научитесь пользоваться консолью. Это не сложно.
При нажатии на кнопку там видно ошибку
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

items[currentIndex-1] undefined

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Ну попробуйте вот этот код. И посмотрите консоль `const a = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(a[-1])`. У вас currentIndex отрицательный. Там нет ничего под этим индексом в массиве.

Comment: but.js:47 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null
    at HTMLButtonElement.nextSlide (but.js:47)